# Checkout Subversion last changes to upload to FTP

Tags: php, svn, svn-checkout

If I make small changes in let's say five different files and commit these to Subversion, how can I checkout just exactly these files in original folder structure to upload and overwrite on FTP Server later on?

If I try to check out HEAD non recursive I just get index.php and some different files which have nothing in common with last changes.

---

Attached solution:
I made a small script - not very elegant but it works ...

```
#!/bin/bash
URL='http://svn ...';
TARGET='./ftp';

read -p "Please enter start revision: " VERSION1
read -p "Please enter ending revision: " VERSION2
read -p "Remove old? [yes] " remove

# getting changes
svn diff $URL --summarize -r$VERSION1:$VERSION2 > changes

# checkout complete revision
svn checkout  $URL -r HEAD

# remove previous
if [ $remove = 'yes'] ; then
if [ -d $TARGET ] ; then
    rm -r $TARGET   
else
    mkdir $TARGET   
fi
fi

for entry in `cat changes`; do
    e=${entry#*$URL/}
    item=$TARGET'/'$e;
    DIR=${item%/*} 

    # create directory
    if [ -d $DIR ] ; then
        echo '';
    else
        mkdir -p $DIR
    fi

    cp './trunk/'$e $DIR
    echo $e
done

echo "Done ..."
read any
```

It checks out the complete trunk and extracting the files which were changed in range of revisions given.

Comment: Id use [`rsync`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync) with checksum (`-c`) comparison to transfer the files instead of FTP, that way it shouldnt matter - it will only replace whats changed. if its more complex than that you can always use specific includes or excludes.

Comment: if you'll do diff on WC (No URL in diff) you already have checkouted repository and can copy files from WC (change order of commands, more correct - checkout outside script once, do svn up before svn diff)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the root of existing working copy

```
svn diff --summarize -rN:M
```

and work with second column

Answer (score 0):

If you have full control of your server, you can `svn checkout` the particular repo path on the target server, and then run an `svn update` to acquire the latest files as needed.

Comment: Can you give me a command line, my problem is that I don't get the current files. I get just index.php